# Can I save created paypal plan and use them for billing agreement

Tags: php, paypal

I'm integrating paypal php sdk into my system. When I try to create a new billing agreement,

1. I create a new Plan
2. I active the Plan just created
3. I create a new Agreement and set plan and payer to this Agreement
4. After user has confirmed this payment, I execute it with the token I received and the apiContext.

The problem is, I do not want to create a new plan each time. because I will only have four subscription, for example, $5, $10, $20, $50 infinite payment monthly. So can I create them once, and save the plan id in my config file, and use the id each time I create a new Agreement for a user. Is there gonna be any potential problem?
I can easily do this with Stripe, but paypal doc is not very clear. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's covered here:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/recurring-payments/

Comment: @gview, I'm confused. That link seems not what I need. It was just how you set up a recurring payment. what I want to create is a billing agreement

Comment: A billing agreement is the basis for recurring payments.  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements  I'm not sure what you are talking about, if it doesn't involve those.  You stated you had subscriptions.  Subscriptions = recurring billing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is 2 years old question so this answer is not relevant to the topicstarter anymore, I would still leave the explanations here.

> because I will only have four subscription, for example, $5, $10, $20, $50 infinite payment monthly. So can I create them once, and save the plan id in my config file, and use the id each time I create a new Agreement for a user.

That's exactly what you do with the Billing Plan. It's explained in [PayPal Billing Plans API docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1/). Whole subscription process is explained here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/#billing-plans.

In your case you should create four billing plans, and when somebody goes to your service and wants to subscribe to one of them, you create a new Billing Agreement based on the ID of the desired Billing Plan, and send its URL to the user to accept.